# KSH check if string starts with substring

Tags: shell, string, ksh

I need to check if the variable has value of string which starts with specified substring.

In Python it would be something like this:

```
foo = 'abcdef'
if foo.startswith('abc'):
    print 'Success'
```

What is the most explicit way to check in Ksh whether strig `$foo` starts with substring `bar`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's very simple but looks a bit odd:

```
if [[ "$foo" == abc* ]]; then ...
```

One would assume that ksh would expand the pattern with the files in the current directory but instead, it does pattern matching. You need the `[[`, though. Single `[` won't work. The quotes are not strictly necessary if there are no blanks in `foo`.

Comment: Inside double brackets, you don't need the quotes even if `$foo` is null or unset.

Comment: The solution looks exactly like what I was looking for. But unfortunately it doesn't work in my ksh. It looks like ksh88, I guess too old for such tricks.

Comment: What if `$foo` has "=" in it?

Comment: @user443854: BASH expansion works in such a way that the `if` command gets the contents of `foo` as a single parameter, so it doesn't matter. And the `if` command only looks for a parameter which is exactly `=`, it doesn't try to split parameters further.

Answer (score 17):

Also:

```
foo='abcdef'
pattern='abc*'

case "$foo" in
    $pattern) echo startswith ;;
    *) echo otherwise ;;
esac
```

Comment: You certainly don't need the interim variable. `case $foo in 'abc'* ) echo yes ;; esac`

Comment: portable back to solaris 9 /bin/sh and @tripleee's simplification above works

Answer (score 6):

You can also do regex matching:

```
if [[ $foo =~ ^abc ]]
```

For more complex patterns, I recommend using a variable instead of putting the pattern directly in the test:

```
bar='^begin (abc|def|ghi)[^ ]* end$'
if [[ $foo =~ $bar ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/ksh
case ${foo:0:3} in
    abc) echo success;;
      *) echo failure;;
esac
```