# Matching only the first three numbers of a string in ksh

Tags: shell, variables, awk, ksh

```
VARIABLE=`grep PortNumber` testfile.txt | awk -F'"' '{print $2}'`
echo $VARIABLE
33111
```

I want to do a check to ensure the first 2 numbers of the variable are the digit '3' only.

How can I do this using a standard ksh script?

EDIT:
I think I have it in the following, does this look correct?
echo $VARIABLE | egrep -q '^[3]{2}'

Comment: I think that has been asked.  Did this not work for you: [ksh-check-if-string-starts-with-substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080388/ksh-check-if-string-starts-with-substring)

Comment: May be my understanding that's not clear but I can't see an answer in that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
echo $VARIABLE |  grep -E "^3+{2}"
```